# How to create a horizontal carousel (with each pic being a link to a site)

Tags: html, pagination, carousel

(I created a post that was taken down because I don't think I gave enough info or something? I added more here, including the html code that I put together. Please let me know if this is not acceptable.)

I am trying to create a horizontal carousel where you can click the images that are linked to other pages. I have tried multiple types of carousels through HTML that I found on w3schools.com and other websites, but none of them were exactly what I was looking for. Here is what I was able to put together but it just isn't what I'm looking for. It doesn't scroll through the images like a carousel. I would also like to make the images links. Any suggestions?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

/* Position the image container (needed to position the left and right arrows) */
.container {
  position: relative;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

/* Add a pointer when hovering over the thumbnail images */
.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* Container for image text */
.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #222;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Six columns side by side */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 16.66%;
}

/* Add a transparency effect for thumnbail images */
.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
</style>
<body>

<div class="container">
  
    
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

  <div class="caption-container">
    <p id="caption"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="image1.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="Lagoon">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="image2.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Airport">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="image3.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="Plants">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="image4.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="Jeep">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="image5.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(5)" alt="Lagoon Again">
    </div>    
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="image6.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(6)" alt="Airport Again">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}
</script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a second one that I tried but it's just not right:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.pagination a {
  color: black;
  float: left;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background-color .3s;
}

.pagination a.active {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
}

.pagination a:hover:not(.active) {background-color: #ddd;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="pagination">
  <a href="#">&laquo;</a>
  <a href="example.com" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener"><img src="https://example.com/image1.jpg" alt="Throw" style="float: left; width: 25%; margin-right: 1.0em; margin-bottom: 1.0em;"></a>
  <a href="example.com" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener"><img src="https://example.com/image2.jpg" alt="room" style="float: left; width: 22%; margin-right: 1.0em; margin-bottom: 1.0em;"></a>
  <a href="example.com" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener"><img src="https://example.com/image3.jpg" alt=" sectional" style="float: left; width: 25%; margin-right: 1.0em; margin-bottom: 1.0em;"></a>
  <a href="example.com" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener"><img src="https://example.com/image4.jpg" alt="1970" style="float: left; width: 17%; margin-right: 1.0em; margin-bottom: 1.0em;"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://example.com/image5.jpg" alt="home" style="float: left; width: 17%; margin-right: 1.0em; margin-bottom: 1.0em;"></a>
  <a href="example.com" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener"><img src="https://exmple.com/image6.jpeg" alt="home" style="float: left; width: 17%; margin-right: 1.0em; margin-bottom: 1.0em;"></a>
  <a href="#">&raquo;</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here are two examples of what I would want it to look like:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why dont you try owl carousel ? its easy and simple. You can also try slick slider also.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks for the help!